# For .NET Maui, attaching a single FlyoutMenu to several view elements

Tags: maui, popupmenu

For .NET maui;

I have a MenuFlyout, have two context items added to it. And I'm attaching this right click context menu to two seperate labels:

```
Label label1=new Label(){Text="MyLabel1"};
Label label2=new Label(){Text="MyLabel2"};
MenuFlyout menuElements = new MenuFlyout();
MenuFlyoutItem item1 = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "menu1" };
MenuFlyoutItem item2 = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "menu2" };
item1.Clicked+=async(s,e)=>
{
//menu1 click fires here when clicking both labels, but i can't catch which label is clicked
};

menuElements.Add(item1);
menuElements.Add(item2);

FlyoutBase.SetContextFlyout(label1, menuElements);
FlyoutBase.SetContextFlyout(label2, menuElements);
```

Popup menu shows for each label and click event fires for menu items. Is it possible to catch the element (label that is right clicked) that shows the popup menu in the Clicked event?

--

EDIT: for windows (winui) it is possible to create a handler for right click, and set which label is right clicked silently before popup is shown. so i can use that in Clicked event. But I need this for macCatalyst. I couldn't find a workaround for handling right click in macCatalyst

```
#if MACCATALYST
  handler.PlatformView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
  UITapGestureRecognizer gesture=new UITapGestureRecognizer(MACC_HandleRightClick);
  gesture.ButtonMaskRequired= UIEventButtonMask.Secondary;
  handler.PlatformView.AddGestureRecognizer(gesture);

//MAC_HandleRightClick isn't called on right click
#endif
```

--

Regards

Comment: 1. Looks like the UITapGestureRecognizer responds to double taps, is it a single tap or double taps. 2. Can you help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can reproduce it?

Comment: Yes sure, im creating an example for this

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/18233#discussioncomment-7396250

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll look into this and see if could figure out a workaround for handling right click in MacCatalyst.

Comment: Thank you @AlexandarMay-MSFT. As a workaround, first i set the hovergesturerecognizers for labels (i suppose one cannot right click a label without hovering it) and set the HoveredLabel variable. Then used that info at Clicked event of menu items. Solved my case, but i still prefer handling right click

Comment: Good job! You can post your workaround as an answer as potentially it will help others who have similar issue!